# Fixed length of a string in a string

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Im building this string:

```
text_ := 'NAME           LNAME         AGE'||chr(13)||chr(10);

FOR person_ IN list LOOP

text_ := text_ ||person_.name||'     '||person_.lname||'      '||person_.age||chr(13)||chr(10);

END LOOP;
```

Loop will result in:

```
NAME           LNAME            AGE
name           lname            18
namename            lname           18
```

Desired result:

```
NAME           LNAME            AGE
name           lname            18
namename       lname            18
```

Is there a way to tell a string to fill itself with whitespace if the value within it doesn't reach a fixed value?

Using RPAD:

```
  text_ := text_||rpad('Name', 30)||rpad('Date', 12)||chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10);

  FOR op_ IN get_op LOOP
    text_ := text_||rpad(op_.NAME, 30)||rpad(op_.DATE,12)||chr(13)||chr(10);
  END LOOP;
```

Results in:

```
Name                          Date      

UserUserUser                    2014-04-03                                                   
UserUser                      2014-04-04
UserUser                      2014-04-03
```

Comment: Is this the exact output in 'Results in:'. Did you copy paste it? First line of date has 2 extra spaces while Name is 4 characters longer.

Comment: No it's not an exact copy paste. But it looks like that.

Comment: As commented in answer below I think it looks like that because you use a proportional typeface. Open an editor (Notepad) , choose a monospace font (Lucida Console) and copy-paste output into editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rpad

```
text_ := text_ ||rpad(person_.name,40)||rpad(person_.lname,40)||rpad(person_.age,40)||chr(13)||chr(10);
```

Test Case

```
DECLARE
   t VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   t := RPAD('NAME',10)||RPAD('LNAME',10)||RPAD('AGE',10)||chr(13)||chr(10);
   FOR i IN 8..11
   LOOP
      t := t ||RPAD('Name'||i,10)||RPAD('lname'||i,10)||RPAD(i,10)||chr(13)||chr(10);
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line(t);
END;
```

Output:

```
NAME      LNAME     AGE       
Name8     lname8    8         
Name9     lname9    9         
Name10    lname10   10        
Name11    lname11   11
```

Comment: Doesn't work, everything still get shifted to the left.

Comment: Are you using a monospace font to display the results?

Comment: Actually you're right copy/pasting it gives a correct layout in notepad. I'm sending my text_ into a mail function that mail it to my mail. Somewhere there's the error.